# gawk to read last bit of binary data over a pipe without timeout?

Tags: http, awk, wget, gawk

I have a program already written in gawk that downloads a lot of small bits of info from the internet. (A media scanner and indexer)

At present it launches wget to get the information. This is fine, but I'd like to *simply* reuse the connection between invocations. Its possible a run of the program might make between 200-2000 calls to the same api service.

I've just discovered that gawk can do networking and found [geturl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawkinet/html_node/GETURL.html)
However the advice at the bottom of that page is well heeded, I can't find an easy way to read the last line and keep the connection open.

As I'm mostly reading JSON data, I can set RS="}" and exit when body length reaches the expected content-length. This might break with any trailing white space though. I'd like a more robust approach. Does anyone have a nicer way to implement sporadic http requests in awk that keep the connection open. Currently I have the following structure...

```
con="/inet/tcp/0/host/80";

send_http_request(con);

RS="\r\n";

read_headers();

# now read the body - but do not close the connection...
RS="}"; # for JSON
while ( con |& getline bytes ) {
    body = body bytes RS;
    if (length(body) >= content_length) break;
    print length(body);
}
# Do not close con here - keep open
```

Its a shame this one little thing seems to be spoiling all the potential here. Also in case anyone asks :) ..

- awk was originally chosen for historical reasons - there were not many other language options on this embedded platform at the time.
- Gathering up all of the URLs in advance and passing to wget will not be easy.
- re-implementing in perl/python etc is not a quick solution.
- I've looked at trying to pipe urls to a named pipe and into wget -i - , that doesn't work. Data gets buffered, and unbuffer not available - also I think wget gathers up all the URLS until EOF before processing.
- The data is small so lack of compression is not an issue.

Comment: Is it fair game to replace just the `wget` portion? I have to think that writing a replacement for `wget` that sticks around, reads URLs off stdin, and writes data to stdout would be far easier than trying to build the functionality into a `gawk` script.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, but you may find this discussion of some value : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/RinvdXVq11o . There are other discussions also, search for wget and inet/tcp . Good luck and if you figure this out, please post your answer!

Comment: Just a quick update, I implemented a hackish version that would check the host, content-type and content-encoding to decide on the best delimiter to use. It was reusing connections OK, but on this particular embedded system (NMT), all performance gains from reusing the connection were lost by the speed at which it read the body (or maybe general IO / string speed). No real gains over spawning additional wget process.

Comment: @sarnold - I might do that at some point. I've spent more time on this than I should have with nothing to show - but I learned about gawk networking and how to process chunked encoding :)

Comment: @shelter - Thanks - It sounds like a case of using the right tool for the right job. Shame one "little" code change to wget would be really useful.

Comment: @ydrol: Can we follow up on this off-line. I possibly have the time to work on this. See my http://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter for contact info.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the connection reuse comes from the HTTP 1.0 standard, not gawk.  To reuse the connection you must either [use HTTP 1.1 or try some other non-standard solutions for HTTP 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).  Don't forget to add the `Host:` header in your HTTP/1.1 request, as it is mandatory.

You're right about the lack of robustness when reading the response body.  For line oriented protocols this is not an issue.  Moreover, even when using HTTP 1.1, if your scripts locks waiting for more data when it shouldn't, the server will, again, close the connection due to inactivity.

As a last resort, you could write your own HTTP retriever in whatever langauage you like which reuses connections (all to the same remote host I presume) and also inserts a special record separator for you.  Then, you could control it [from the awk script](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO).

Comment: Thanks for response, I'm using HTTP 1.1 ok, and reconnecting is handled very nicely in awk. its just that , as you point out, unless I read the very last byte of the response body then the connection may not get reused, and if I try to read too much, then it will block waiting for more input from the server.